# save order prestashop web service

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

I'm newbie with prestashop webservice, I'm trying to save orders in prestashop 
database but i'm getting this error : table ps_orders doesn't exist, which is normal because prefix of my tables is different than ps_  :

here is my code :

`define('DEBUG', true);
define('PS_SHOP_PATH', 'http://localhost/prestashop');
define('PS_WS_AUTH_KEY', 'CQP84L4R3GB6IV99E5WSP4JPSWXDYE1R');
require_once('./PSWebServiceLibrary.php');
 try{
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice(PS_SHOP_PATH, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY, DEBUG);
$xml = $webService->get( array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH.'/api/carts?schema=blank') );
$resources = $xml->children()->children();

$id_currency = 3;
$id_lang = 2;
$id_product = 2571;
// $attribute_product =
$id_address = 8;
$qte_product = 1;
$id_customer = 3;
$id_carrier = 3;
$date_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');


$name_product = 'produit 111 ';
// $reference_product = ;
$price_product = 320;
$tax_inclu_product = 320;
$tax_excl_product = 320;
$order_module = 'cashondelivery';
$order_payment = 'Cash on delivery (COD)';
$total_paid = 355;
$total_paid_real = 355;
$total_products = $price_product;
$total_products_wt = $price_product;
$id_status = 5; // status de la commande : livré, en cours         
$total_discounts =0;
$total_discounts_tax_incl = $total_discounts;
$total_discounts_tax_excl = $total_discounts;
$total_paid_tax_incl = 355;
$total_paid_tax_excl = 355;

$total_shipping = 35 ; //frais selon la ville de livraison
$total_shipping_tax_incl = $total_shipping;
$total_shipping_tax_excl = $total_shipping;


$xml->cart->id_currency  = $id_currency;
$xml->cart->id_lang      = $id_lang;
$xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[0]->id_product            = $id_product;
// $xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[0]->id_product_attribute  = $attribute_product;
$xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[0]->id_address_delivery   = $id_address;
$xml->cart->associations->cart_rows->cart_row[0]->quantity              = $qte_product;
// Others
$xml->cart->id_address_delivery = $id_address;
$xml->cart->id_address_invoice  = $id_address;
$xml->cart->id_customer         = $id_customer;
$xml->cart->id_carrier          = $id_carrier;
$xml->cart->date_add            = $date_now;
$xml->cart->date_upd            = $date_now;

// Adding the new customer's cart        
$opt = array( 'resource' => 'carts' );
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add( $opt );

$id_cart = $xml->cart->id;   

//  ORDER 

$xml = $webService->get(array('url' => PS_SHOP_PATH .'/api/orders/?schema=blank'));

// Adding dinamic and required fields
// Required
$xml->order->id_address_delivery    = $id_address; // Customer address
$xml->order->id_address_invoice     = $id_address;        
$xml->order->id_cart                = $id_cart; 
$xml->order->id_currency            = $id_currency;
$xml->order->id_lang                = $id_lang;
$xml->order->id_customer            = $id_customer; 
$xml->order->id_carrier             = $id_carrier;
$xml->order->module                 = $order_module;
$xml->order->payment                = $order_payment;        
$xml->order->total_paid             = $total_paid;
$xml->order->total_paid_real        = $total_paid_real;
$xml->order->total_products         = $total_products;
$xml->order->total_products_wt      = $total_products_wt;
$xml->order->conversion_rate        = 1;
        // Others
$xml->order->valid                  = 1; 
$xml->order->current_state              = 1;        
$xml->order->total_discounts            = $total_discounts;
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_incl   = $total_discounts_tax_incl;
$xml->order->total_discounts_tax_excl   = $total_discounts_tax_excl;
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_incl        = $total_paid_tax_incl;
$xml->order->total_paid_tax_excl        = $total_paid_tax_excl;
$xml->order->total_shipping             = $total_shipping;
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_incl    = $total_shipping_tax_incl;
$xml->order->total_shipping_tax_excl    = $total_shipping_tax_excl;
// Order Row. Required
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_id             = $id_product;
//$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_attribute_id   = $attribute_product;
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_quantity       = $qte_product;
// Order Row. Others
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_name           = $name_product;
// $xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_reference      = $reference_produc;
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->product_price          = $price_product;
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->unit_price_tax_incl    = $tax_inclu_product;
$xml->order->associations->order_rows->order_row[0]->unit_price_tax_excl    = $tax_excl_product;

// Creating the order
$opt = array( 'resource' => 'orders' );
$opt['postXml'] = $xml->asXML();
$xml = $webService->add( $opt );
$id_order = $xml->order->id;   

echo "Customer 1 : ".$id_customer." address: ".$id_address." cart: ".$id_cart." Order: .".$id_order;

}  catch (PrestaShopWebserviceException $e) {

  // Here we are dealing with errors
  $trace = $e->getTrace();
  if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 404) echo 'Bad ID';
  else if ($trace[0]['args'][0] == 401) echo 'Bad auth key';
  else echo 'Other error<br />'.$e->getMessage();
}`

[image]

Comment: So change the prefix.

Comment: I don't know where do I have to change it. I still searching in PS doc but can't find this information yet

Comment: config >setting.inc.php

Comment: in config>setting, the variable _DB_PREFIX_ is already set I don't have any problem to access to my shop. it's when I test my script that use Prestashop Web service that I get this error